# Origin destination plot

Tags: r, stplanr

I am looking for a way to add more information to this Origin-Destinatio plot. First i would like to add a label to each of the zones (origin/ destination). Secondly, I would also like to plot a map as a background and possibly add a color gradient to the plot.

Example datasets are included in the package stplanR. I use a different dataset.
This is my code so far:

```
library(stplanr)

library(tidyverse)

library(sp)

Cents <- read.table(...)

str(Cents)

head(Cents)

coords <- Cents[,c("lat","lon")]

data <- as.data.frame( Cents[,1])

crs    <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992") # proj4string of coords

Centssp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords      = coords,
                               data        = data, 
                               proj4string = crs)

Flows <- read.table(...)

l <- od2line(flow = Flows, zones = Centssp)
l
plot(l, lwd = l$MotorisedTraffic / 5)`
```

Thanks in advance!

edit: code with example datasets

````
l <- od2line(flow = flow, zones = cents)
l
# remove lines with no length

plot(l, lwd = l$All / 5 )```
````

Comment: Could you adjust your code to use one of the example datasets so we have a place to start?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dave. I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

To add a map to the background, try

```
plot(l, lwd = l$All / 5 )
plot(map, add=T) #add this for a map
```